# Managing multiple AWS Console logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-iam

I have several AWS Console logins provided by various unrelated clients. If i'm working on multiple clients at once this means essentially using multiple browsers and their private mode to keep them all open.

Does anybody have a more elegant solution to this? They are for different clients so AWS Organisations is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

The AWS Management Console allows you to **switch roles**.

- Create a role in each account you would like to use
- Establish a trust relationship between that role and your normal IAM User
- In the management console, supply the ARN of the role you'd like to switch to
- Switch to it!

However, I suspect that you can't have multiple tabs open to different roles -- but it makes it much easier to switch in and out of different roles without having to login to each one.

See: [Switching to a Role (Console) - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html)

Comment: You suspect right. When using Chrome, all tabs automatically switch to the new role. To have different roles in different tabs, you will need something like Ghost Browser.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is the correct way of doing it, though I would suggest you another way.

Login chrome  with separate Gmail account create a separate user for browser  or Mozilla pocket account   you can now use them to open multiple aws account

[image]

Comment: I think this is closest to what the OP was after. I posted a variant of this question & answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280046/how-can-i-have-multiple-concurrent-aws-console-sessions-logged-in-to-multiple-ac/65280047#65280047

Answer (score 0):

Each and every console account you create or login is eligible to have 3 or more accounts merged with it. So in complete you can have more accounts handled with the same user but different login credentials.

Hope my answer might help you in some way.

All the best..

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?

Comment: I am just using the resources that are provided by the AWS which helps us to not strain and gain a lot out of it. Please go through the link provided below and do please reply if it is good enough, if not I'll try to provide any other. https://akhil0087.home.blog/2019/11/23/creating-multiple-users-iam-in-aws/

Answer (score 0):

You can even check with AWS organization, which helps you in creating additional 3 root accounts under same billing details

Answer (score 0):

we are using `aws extend switch roles` chrome extension at my work place. it's very handy.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aws-extend-switch-roles/jpmkfafbacpgapdghgdpembnojdlgkdl?hl=en

It is useful when assuming roles especially cross accounts.

In your case, its totally unrelated accounts from unrelated clients. I guess it would be easier to use separate chrome profiles one per client. Or you can use `Ghost Browser`, it's a chromium based browser allows to create work spaces, you can even have different sessions in different tabs.

hope this helps.